# can i get the grey cowl of nocturnal in any of the dlc's?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard, skyrim-hearthfire

[image] can someone please just answer my question without any difficult answers I'm kinda exhausted from searching to see if I can and I still haven't gotten an answer can I get it in the dlc or not

Answer (score 3):

The provided image seems like part of a player-made mod, the Grey Cowl is in Elder Scrolls: Oblivion, but not in Skyrim.

Answer (score 0):

Not in-game, but there is a [mod](http://nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/38458?) though. Tthey also use the same image you used.